# Adding multiple users into a single record Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

So I have an app rails 5, ruby 2.4.0.

I have a truck model and a user model.

when a user creates a new Truck, they need to add an owner and a driver (both users)

When this record is created it automatically saves the user who created the record aswell.

right now when I add a new truck the User id is saved and the owner_id and driver_id are also saved.

when I try to list the owner, driver and user names on the record, they over write each other, I am also now getting this error:

[image: Better Errors screenshot]

my Truck model:

```
class Truck < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end
```

my user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :invitable

  has_many :trip_categories
  has_many :trucks

end
```

my trucks controller (show action):

```
class TrucksController < ApplicationController

  # GET /trucks/1
  # GET /trucks/1.json
def show
   @truck = Truck.find(params[:id])
   @truck.owner_id = User.find_by(params[:owner_id])
   @truck.driver_id = User.find_by(params[:driver_id])
   @truck.user = User.find_by(params[:user_id])
 end


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_truck
      @truck = Truck.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def truck_params
      params.require(:truck).permit(:make, :model, :color, :vin, :unit_number, :owner_id, :driver_id, :user_id)
    end
end
```

Its been a long while since I've done anything like this any help here would be greatly appreciated, Please let me know if anything else is needed for help in troubleshooting this problem.

EDIT 1: Add screenshot of new error:

[image: Better errors screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add two relationships between user and truck as following

```
class User
  has_many :own_trucks, as: :owner, class_name: 'Truck'
  has_many :driving_trucks, as: :driver, class_name: 'Truck'
end

class Truck
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :driver, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :user, class_name: 'User' <-- added - Edited to provide full answer to solution
end



def create
  # @truck = Truck.new
  # @truck.owner = User.find(params[:owner_id])
  # @truck.driver = User.find(params[:driver_id])
  @truck = Truck.new(params.permit(:driver_id, :owner_id, :xxxx1, :xxxx2))
  @truck.save
end

def show
  @truck = Truck.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: so that works great! except now when i get to the show page i get the error i posted above

Comment: im assigning the owner and driver and user so i can convert the id's displayed to the respective name of the users assigned to it

Comment: truck.owner = xxx
truck.driver = xxx
truck.save

Comment: you lost me there?

Comment: I have edit the answer, you should assign the owner and driver when the truck is  created, and save it into database

Comment: ok so thats working for the most part.. i can display the name of the owner and driver but get a no method error when trying to attach the created_by or user_id name attribute

Comment: hummm....  You can add a belongs_to relationship such as belongs_to :user or belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'

Comment: I had to add another belongs_to in the Truck model ill edit

Comment: It is different relationship, i think you'd better add another belongs_to

Answer (score 1):

`has_many :users` adds an instance method `users` to the Truck class.

You can add users like

```
@truck.users << user1
@truck.users << user2
@truck.users << user3
# or equivalently
@truck.users << [user1, user2, user3]
```

Regarding EDIT1, you should `has_many :users` does not add `user` method,
so the error says it is undefined.